# Express/MongoDB - Unexpected behavior during a database operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, callback

I have a list of users that I try to store/update into my mongoDB database.
But only the last element from my list is taken into account, the others users don't enter into `then` function.

I'm newbie in Nodejs and this seems to be due to a synchronicity behavior that I don't understand.

```
var User = require('../to/path/user-service');
....
userList.forEach(function(user) {
    try {
            User.updateUser(user);
    } catch(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }   

});
```

**user-service**

```
...
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
console.log(user.name);     
export.updateUser = function (user) {
    Issue.findOne({name: user.name})
        .then((user) => {
            if(user) console.log(user.name + ' has been updated');
            else console.log(user.name + ' has been created');
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
};
```

**Ouput**

```
John
Paul
Alex
Alex has been created
Alex has been created
Alex has been created
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with JavaScript closures. When you add a function to the function queue, it and its variables are added. In this case the variable `user` is added. When the function terminates and the updateUser() functions are called, the `user` variable is Alex, so Alex gets added three times. Read more about closures here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Here is one way to fix your issue:

```
userList.forEach(function(user) {
    var closureUser = user;
    try {
            console.log(closureUser.name);     
            closureUser.updateUser(closureUser);
    } catch(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: I added your modification but I still have the same issue.

Comment: My real code is litte bit different. By taking into account the closure mechanism I finally had what I'm expected. Thanks